# Rewrite of counter by partition

Tags: php, mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

I use mysql and php with phpmyadmin. I have major problem with a partition based counter that I wan't to improve but my knowledge on sql prevents me from doing that. Im struggling very much with this.

I want the duplicated data in my table to have a counter that adds a number after a value if this value gets a duplicated value and then restarts from 1 until a new value is met and so on. Here is what the final result should look like

```
---------------------------
1  | Josh-1
---------------------------
2  | Josh-2
--------------------------
3  | Josh-3 
--------------------------
4  | Josh-4 
--------------------------
5  | Fred-1 
--------------------------
6  | Fred-2
--------------------------
7  | Fred-3
-------------------------
```

I had gotten help with this counter here before but it's not working as I wan't it to. Also when I have pressed the insert button in my form the table looks like this in phpmyadmin after I reload it

```
---------------------------
1  | Josh-1-1-1
---------------------------
2  | Josh-2
--------------------------
3  | Josh-3 
--------------------------
4  | Josh-4 
--------------------------
5  | Fred-1 
--------------------------
6  | Fred-2
--------------------------
7  | Fred
-------------------------
```

Whats going on here? The code that I seek help with rewriting is this

```
UPDATE usermeta u1,
(SELECT
u1.`id`, CONCAT(u1.`name`,'-',ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY u1.`name` ORDER BY u1.`id`)) newname
FROM 
usermeta u1 JOIN (SELECT `name` , COUNT(*) FROM usermeta GROUP BY `name` HAVING COUNT(*) > 1) u2
ON u1.`name` = u2.`name` ) u3
SET u1.`name` = u3.`newname`
WHERE u1.`id` = u3.`id`
```

Could this code be rewritten so it creates a table of numbered names and duplicates that looks like the first table example and work like it should in phpmyadmin ? All help is very much appreciated. Keep in mind that I am a struggling moderate sql user.

Comment: *The code that I seek help with rewriting is this* This code may produce duplicates in concurrent environ.

Answer (score 0):

Possible solution - BEFORE INSERT trigger and additional MyISAM table with secondary autoincrement:

Working table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
>                    name VARCHAR(127));
> ```

Additional table

> ```
> CREATE TABLE user_index (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
>                          name VARCHAR(127),
>                          PRIMARY KEY (name, id)) ENGINE=MyISAM;
> ```

Trigger

> ```
> CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_index
> BEFORE INSERT ON user
> FOR EACH ROW
> BEGIN
>     DECLARE new_index INT;
>     INSERT INTO user_index (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
>     SET new_index = LAST_INSERT_ID();
>     DELETE FROM user_index WHERE name = NEW.name AND id < new_index;
>     SET NEW.name = CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.name, new_index);
> END
> ```

Insert rows - the AI index is added to the name. Check the result.

> ```
> INSERT INTO user (name) VALUES
> ('Josh'),
> ('Josh'),
> ('Fred'),
> ('Josh'),
> ('Fred'),
> ('Fred'),
> ('Josh');
> SELECT * FROM user;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name  
> -: | :-----
>  1 | Josh-1
>  2 | Josh-2
>  3 | Fred-1
>  4 | Josh-3
>  5 | Fred-2
>  6 | Fred-3
>  7 | Josh-4
> ```

Look what is stored in additional table now.

> ```
> SELECT * FROM user_index;
> ```
>
> ```
> id | name
> -: | :---
>  3 | Fred
>  4 | Josh
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=c649728a3c6aecc0b08610b15ecec62f)*

---

If your working table `user` exists already, and it contains some data, then you'd create additional table and fill it with data using, for example,

```sql
CREATE TABLE user_index (id INT AUTO_INCREMENT,
                         name VARCHAR(127),
                         PRIMARY KEY (name, id)) ENGINE=MyISAM
SELECT MAX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', -1) + 0) id,
       SUBSTRING_INDEX(name, '-', 1) name
FROM user
GROUP BY 2;
```

https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=38f028cfe1c9e85188ab0454463dcd78

Comment: If I am not wrong then I should use the sql code in my php insert string? Like the this $insert_sql = "CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_index " .  
    "BEFORE INSERT ON user " .
    "FOR EACH ROW " .
    "BEGIN " .
    "DECLARE new_index INT; " .
    "INSERT INTO user_index (name) VALUES (NEW.name); " .
    "SET new_index = LAST_INSERT_ID(); " .
    "DELETE FROM user_index WHERE name = NEW.name AND id < new_index; " .
    "SET NEW.name = CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.name, new_index); " .
    "END ";  Or do I do this in my sql-tables file  in my system? I am also not sure what NEW comes from, sorry.

Comment: @ingmarleifsson Additional table and trigger should be created once, in addition to working table creation, before any insertions. And your PHP code should execute `INSERT INTO user (name) ...` only.

Comment: Sorry for that. I have a file in which I store my tables. Your trigger code looks like this                                                                                     DROP TRIGGER insert_user_index; 
 CREATE TRIGGER insert_user_index
    BEFORE INSERT ON tbl_actor
    FOR EACH ROW
    BEGIN
        DECLARE new_index INT;
        INSERT INTO tbL_actor_index (name) VALUES (NEW.name);
        SET new_index = LAST_INSERT_ID();
        DELETE FROM tbL_actor_index WHERE name = NEW.name AND id < new_index;
        SET NEW.name = CONCAT_WS('-', NEW.name, new_index);
    END

Comment: @ingmarleifsson Do not forget about `DELIMITER` command.

Comment: But the result in phpmyadmin becomes like this Josh Anderson-1-1 after a reload the code adds a -1 after each name. This is weird. I must look for another method. I prefer to use only one table for this counter.

Comment: Thank you for the tip on the delimeter command

Comment: I meant to say after an insert in previous comment not a page reload of phpmyadmin. This is really strange.

Comment: @ingmarleifsson I can say nothing about client-side effects. If you need the page to be reloaded - reload it, maybe explicitly.

Comment: Could someone perhaps post another example on a counter using partition and row_number() functions ? Thats more of what I am trying to accomplish.